# Answering questions about a linear system with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Normally, in solving problems with linear systems, one is given a system of constraints and wishes to find a solution, but in my case I am given a solution and want to find a system for which the given values are a solution.

That is, for $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\alpha, \beta \in (0, \pi/2)$ and $y_i \in (0, \pi/2]$, I want to find a system of form
$$
y_0 + y_1 = \pi + k_1\alpha - l_1\beta \\
y_1 + y_2 = \pi + k_2\alpha - l_2\beta \\
\vdots \\
y_{n-2} + y_{n-1} = \pi + k_{n-1}\alpha - l_{n-1}\beta \\
y_{n-1} + y_0 = \pi + k_n\alpha - l_n\beta \\
$$
where $y_0, \alpha, \beta$ are known and each equality satisfies the constraints given by $y_{i-1} > k_i \alpha$ and $\pi > l_i \beta + y_i$ for $i=1, 2, ..., n$ (in the last equality treat $y_0$ as $y_n$).  In particular I want to know for which values of $\alpha, \beta$ and fixed $y_0$ such a system exists.  For example, if $y_0 = \pi/2$, for any $\alpha, \beta$ can one find a system of the above form?

Comment: "Let" is a term that is normally used to indicate the *known* values in a problem. You use it to introduce *every* variable. What are the parameters whose values you know, and what are the variables whose values you are trying to find?

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for pointing this out.  $\alpha, \beta, y_0$ are known.